# RecyclerView.Adapter's onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder methods are not getting called

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to implement [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/) in my project by following the sample project provided in that link. I have implemented everything and my code works without any errors but the actual List is not getting inflated. Upon debugging I found out that the adapter is set correctly and the `getItemCount` method is also returning positive count but the other two overridden methods `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` are not getting called. I have no clue why it is not working. Please see the partial code below, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**MyAdapter.java** class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < MyViewHolder > {

    private MySimpleCursorAdapter mCursor;
    //some other private fields here

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int resourceId, ViewType viewType, String containerId) {
        mCursor = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6); //Passed necessary arguments
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.w("onCreateViewHolder", "--------->executed"); //Line not executed
        final View view = mCursor.newView(mContext, mCursor.getCursor(), parent);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.w("onBindViewHolder", "--------->executed"); //Line not executed
        mCursor.bindView(holder.itemView, mContext, mCursor.getCursor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.w("count", Integer.toString(mCursor.getCount())); //This is executed
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    private class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayoutToInflate, null);
            ....
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(final View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            //Implemented this method for inflating all subviews inside each item of the list
        }
    }
 }
```

**Note:** I have gone through similar questions but the answers provided there are not relevant to my question because my `RecyclerView` is not inside `ScrollView` and also the `getItemCount` is returning the positive count.

Comment: use this adapter https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Answer (score 9):

I think you forgot the `setLayoutManager(LayoutManager)` on the recycler view. Without Layout Manager, only `getItemCount()` is called.

Try with `yourRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I'm not using the default _LinearLayoutManager_. If you see the sample code [here](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/org/lucasr/twowayview/sample/LayoutFragment.java) (line 128) he's also not using _setLayoutManager_.

Comment: So did you put into the xml file `app:twowayview_layoutManager="ListLayoutManager"` ? (or whatever layoutmanager) like this https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/layout_list.xml#L25

Comment: Yes, I put that in my XML file.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should keep a reference to Context when the Adapter is instantiated:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < MyViewHolder > {

private MySimpleCursorAdapter mCursor;
private Context context;  // <-- add this line
//some other private fields here

public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int resourceId, ViewType viewType, String containerId) {
    mCursor = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6); 
    this.context = context;  // <-- add this line
    //Passed necessary arguments
    ....
}
```

Then, in the onCreateViewHolder method, use that reference to Context to create the view for the ViewHolder:

```
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.w("onCreateViewHolder", "--------->executed"); //Line not executed
    final View view = mCursor.newView(context, mCursor.getCursor(), parent);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```

Then in your CursorAdapter, inflate the view as follows:

```
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(mLayoutToInflate, parent, false);
        return view;
    }
```

I had the same issue, albeit I using a JSON call to retrieve the data instead of the Cursor Adapter, and these changes fixed the problem.